# How do I define my script tag to handle virtual directories?

Tags: directory, virtual

In my index.html file I'm using:

```
     <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

which isn't found if my URL is http://foobar.com/virtual/index.html but is found if the URL is http://foobar.com/index.html. How can I define my script tag so that it's found if a virtual directory is used. I don't want to specify the virtual directory in the script tag because this is being deployed in several places and it may or may not have a virtual directory.

Thanks for any help. This web site has saved my butt many times.

Answer (score 0):

The `src` tag is in reference to the `html` that is using it. In your current scenario if you wish the script src to work in first scenario (`foobar.com/virtual/index.html`), just replace script tag with 
`<script src="../Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`